# Latest stable version of Oracle application express

Tags: oracle11g, upgrade, oracle-apex

We are planning to upgrade our oracle application express from 3.2 version. Could someone advice which is the latest stable version of apex (5.1 or 5.1.2)? Also please advice if any separate license is needed to install the latest versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [their website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/index.html):

> Oracle Application Express Release 5.1.2.00.09 was released on June
>   28, 2017. This is a cumulative patch set for Application Express 5.1.0
>   and Application Express 5.1.1.

You don't need a separate licence, since APEX is a no-cost feature of the Oracle database.

As for upgrading from 3.2 to 5.1 the [Installation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMIG/upgrading-from-previous-Oracle-application-express-release.htm#HTMIG365):

> If you have release 1.5.x, 1.6.x, 2.0.x, 2.2.x, 3.0.x, 3.1.x, 3.2.x,
>   4.0x, 4.1x ,4.2.x or 5.0x of Oracle Application Express, following any of the installation scenarios in this guide upgrades your Oracle
>   Application Express instance to release 5.1 and creates Oracle
>   Application Express 5.1 database objects in a new schema and migrates
>   the application metadata to the new release.

Comment: Thanks tony. Could you please also let me know whether i need to apply the previous patches and then upgrade or i can directly upgrade?

Comment: @Crazy2crack Answer updated (NB I don't know all this stuff of the top of my head: I Googled "apex upgrade 3.2 to 5.1"!)